# Object with text and images detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect a page from a book that has object and text on it. I am currently using surf and The rectangles are hardly drawn  on it. Would SURF be the best method to recognise text?

Scene

[image]
Object to be detected

[image]

Result from SURF detection

[image]

Comment: Why not use OCR and compare the actual strings?

Answer (score 0):

SURF would probably not be the best descriptor for this purpose.
I would approach this problem by running connected component analysis, and then use the distribution pattern of the letter components to match the shape of the text blocks between pages.
If you take the centroid of each component as a single point, the list of points create a sort of shape.

This would probably have problems on pages that only have long monotonous text without breaks or titles, but then any descriptor short of performing optical recognition and comparing text would fail.

On the example you've given, it has a potential of working due to the fact that the lines width are not constant, and there are markers, like the paragraph headers.